# Cannot test Play application with junit because of actors

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, akka

UPDATE/SOLUTION

The problem was more of a conception problem than anything else.
We could resolve it by using the Application.isTest() method and NOT start/end the actors if we are unit-testing the program.

ORIGINAL POST

Hi there,

since my (small) team started using actors in Play!, we get this nice error message each time we want to unit-test our application. FYI, the application is being developed in Java.

```
[error] Test utils.JsonUtilsTest.testBuildingJsonResponseWithPermissionsThrowsNullPointerException failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot create children while terminating or terminated, took 0.48 sec
[error]     at akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:266)
... 
[error]     at Global.startActors(Global.java:1248)
```

so let's take a look at the startActors method in the Global class, which extends GlobalSettings :

```
private void startActors() {
    ActorRef measureFrequencyMaster = RemoteActorsUtils.getInstance().getSystem()
                   .actorOf(Props.create(MeasureFrequencyMaster.class), "MeasureFrequencyMaster");
    BatchMessage msg = new BatchMessage();
    msg.setMessage(MSG.GO_SCHEDULE);
    RemoteActorsUtils.getInstance().getBatchMonitor().tell(msg, ActorRef.noSender());
}
```

Well, I'm not sure this helps a lot. But I also have this onStop method in the Global.java file, which is apparently never called :

```
@Override
public void onStop(Application app) {
    super.onStop(app);
    RemoteActorsUtils.getInstance().getSystem().shutdown();
    if (!RemoteActorsUtils.getInstance().getSystem().isTerminated()) {
        RemoteActorsUtils.getInstance().getSystem().shutdown();
    }

}
```

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You can Mock information used by that method, you can have it use whatever data fits the need of the test. Mockito is a library you can use to do so.

Comment: Run your code before `super.onStop(app)` or inject [ApplicationLifecycle](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.html), see [Remove Global Settings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings)

Comment: @Stultuske : I'm not sure that mocking is an option, since our Actors have to be started in the Global file when we run the application

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik: thanks for the links, I'll have a look at them